# How to get the detail information of one Linux thread

Tags: linux, shell

I already know that `ps -ef` and `top` will list the thread information. In fact, I got a pid via top. I would like to check more detail information about this thread, I remember there should be a Linux command to do so.

Thank you @Shahbaz That's answer my question.

However I still would like to make it clear.

What I want is:

I have a pid, I would like to know more information about this thread like where is the thread start such as which folder? and maybe memory related.

The answer I am waiting actually

```
pmap pid

$pmap 498
498:   ./bin/redis-server redis.conf
0000000000400000    224K r-x--  /var/www/bin/redis-2.2.11/bin/redis-server
0000000000637000     12K rwx--  /var/www/bin/redis-2.2.11/bin/redis-server
000000000063a000     80K rwx--    [ anon ]
0000000011204000  57756K rwx--    [ anon ]
0000003dd7a00000    112K r-x--  /lib64/ld-2.5.so
0000003dd7c1b000      4K r-x--  /lib64/ld-2.5.so
0000003dd7c1c000      4K rwx--  /lib64/ld-2.5.so
0000003dd7e00000   1332K r-x--  /lib64/libc-2.5.so
0000003dd7f4d000   2048K -----  /lib64/libc-2.5.so
0000003dd814d000     16K r-x--  /lib64/libc-2.5.so
0000003dd8151000      4K rwx--  /lib64/libc-2.5.so
0000003dd8152000     20K rwx--    [ anon ]
0000003dd8200000    520K r-x--  /lib64/libm-2.5.so
0000003dd8282000   2044K -----  /lib64/libm-2.5.so
0000003dd8481000      4K r-x--  /lib64/libm-2.5.so
0000003dd8482000      4K rwx--  /lib64/libm-2.5.so
0000003dd8a00000     88K r-x--  /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
0000003dd8a16000   2044K -----  /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
0000003dd8c15000      4K r-x--  /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
0000003dd8c16000      4K rwx--  /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
0000003dd8c17000     16K rwx--    [ anon ]
00002b000ff11000      4K rwx--    [ anon ]
00002b000ff28000    416K rwx--    [ anon ]
00002b000ff91000    480K rwx--    [ anon ]
00002b0010fba000   1536K rwx--    [ anon ]
00007fff90700000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
ffffffffff600000   8192K -----    [ anon ]
 total            77052k
```

I hope that clear. At least, I can find it easy next time. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of information you want?

Comment: `[webusr@*****01 ~]$ ps aux | grep ruby
webusr  7910  0.0  0.0 103268 24088 ?        Sl   10:07   0:01 ruby bluepill.rb` I would like information about which folder this ruby command start?

Comment: @Shahbaz, Sure, It's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what kind of info you are looking for, so I'm going to point you to the ultimate location. See

```
/proc/<pid>
```

There are *many* files in there which are either links to locations of interest to the program or once `cat`-ed would provide you with any information you can think of.

---

`/proc` is a directory. Inside of it there are other directories (take a look at it). For each process, there is a directory named with its pid. In that directory, there are links and *special* files, called /proc entries.

Each special file may have a read or write access. If it has read access, you can simply read it (using `cat` for example) and it would give you useful information. If it has write access, it probably means that it can accept certain kind of data to modify some parameter for the process.

---

> I would like information about which folder this ruby command start?

If you know the pid of the `grep` command, do `readlink /proc/<pid>/cwd` to see where the "current working directory" of the process is.

---

On your edit: The same information `pmap` is giving you can be found in `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Comment: Is that a shell script? or command I can use to help me analyse the system?